# Migrations in Laravel 5+

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way to execute migrations on a Laravel application,  in order to update current database structure,
but without destroying the existing data? I am using a mysql database.

I tried:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

But it destroys and recreates the whole database structure.

How do I avoid that?

Comment: the only way is to edit your database structure manually without migration command

Comment: Migrations are supposed to be written in a manner that doesn't require you to run `php artisan migrate:fresh` (or `refresh`, etc). When you write a migration, there's an `up` and `down` function, for moving forward and moving backward. If written properly, you should only ever have to run `php artisan migrate` (forward). Describe your issue better; what are you trying to migrate? Why do you think you have to run `migrate:fresh`? Etc etc.

Comment: You should use artisan:migrate to migrate all outstanding migrations. Read more of Laravel official documentation on this topic.

Comment: @Tim Lewis, I want to execute the command like `php artisan migrate:fresh` to avoid editing database structure manualy, after migrations update...

Comment: Write a new migration that changes the structure, then run `php artisan migrate`. Please re-read my comment; **you shouldn't have to run `php artisan migrate:fresh` if you're using migrations properly.**

Comment: @Tim Lewis, It's clear, that `php artisan migrate:fresh` is unusefull in this case. If I create the new migration with `up` function for existing table, I get error.. So , I mean is there a way to update table structure running migrations?

Comment: "*is there a way to update table structure running migrations?*" - Yes, there is, and you should be doing that. Create a new migration, like `change_column_whatever`, define the logic in `up()` to change the table (add a column, change a column, remove a column, etc), then run `php artisan migrate` (to move forward). `migrate:fresh` nukes and rebuilds the database, which will change the structure if you edited previous migrations, but is not the right approach if you have existing data in your database.

Comment: What is the error? It sounds like you might be editing existing migrations after you ran them. If you want to modify a table after a migration has ran, you need to create a new migration

Comment: >If I create the new migration with up function for existing table, I get error
This could also mean your new migration is trying to re-create the table instead of modifying it

Comment: @Tim Lewis, thank you so far, that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [orangehill/iseed](https://github.com/orangehill/iseed) package.

Follow these steps:

```
 - composer require orangehill/iseed
 - php artisan iseed my_table,another_table
 - composer dump-autoload
 - php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

**Note:**
 Iseeder maybe generate wrong ordering tables. For example, If some tables have relations with foreign key. If the last command gets you the error about foreign key, then you have to look up /database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder  for (ordering of seeders).

Answer (score 1):

The only way to update current database structure using Laravel migrations is to create the new migration with definition of logic in up() function in order to change the table structure. Then run

```
php artisan migrate
```

in order to apply changes.

```
migrate:fresh
```

Is unusefull in this case, because it destroys the database sructure with data.